# how to call a function on after $http.get returns

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx-store

i have ngrx-store implemented. I am trying to turn on spinner before the http call. and turn it off after the call is returned.

```
   getInspectionDetails(order) {
    this.store.dispatch({ type: SPINNER_VISIBLE, payload: true }) //<-- spinner on
    return this.$http.get(this.url+'api/Inspection/'+order.documentNumber)
        .map(this.httpHelper.extractData)
        .catch(this.httpHelper.handleError)
        .map(payload => ({ type: INSPECT_PURCHASE_ORDER, payload }))
        .subscribe(action => this.store.dispatch(action))});
}
```

now i am trying to use

```
this.store.dispatch({ type: SPINNER_VISIBLE, payload: false })
```

to turn off the spinner. basically it is same call with false payload to turn off the spinner. 
but where should i put this?

Comment: I think you can add  .finally(() => turnOffSpinner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subscribe` method takes 3 parameters:

```
httpRequest.subscribe(
    action => // do something when the value arrives
    error => // do something when error occurres
    () => // do something when observable completes
);
```

or you can use `finally` method on the observable:

```
getInspectionDetails(order) {
  this.store.dispatch({ type: SPINNER_VISIBLE, payload: true }) //<-- spinner on
  return this.$http.get(this.url+'api/Inspection/'+order.documentNumber)
      .map(this.httpHelper.extractData)
      .catch(this.httpHelper.handleError)
      .finally(() => this.store.dispatch({ type: SPINNER_VISIBLE, payload: false }))
      .map(payload => ({ type: INSPECT_PURCHASE_ORDER, payload }))
      .subscribe(action => this.store.dispatch(action));
}
```

Second approach is probably better, as the complete callback will not be fired when error occurred. More about the difference in this issue:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7865